# Remove spaces between a row of scale-transformed td elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a row of td elements laid out nicely.

```js
< table > < tbody >
  < tr > {
    JSON.parse(this.state.data).resultCards.map(function(card) {
      return <td > {
        Math.round(card.deviation * 10000) / 10000
      } < img src = {
        'https://image.deckbrew.com/mtg/multiverseid/546841.jpg'
      }
      /></td > ;
    })
  } < /tr>
</tbody > < /table>
```

In the stylesheet, I'm transforming the td elements down to 0.6 scale:

```css
tr td tr td{       
    background-color: #7B8585;
    color: #F8F8F8;

    transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
    overflow: visible;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

And on hover I'm expanding them to full size again:

```css
tr td tr td:hover{
    color: #7b8585;
    background-color:#d8f2f1;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

So far, so good. Problem is, the layout on the page is as if the `<td>` element is at full size, so there's large gaps between each element that I don't want there. I can't have the style specify a height/width and change the height/width on hover because there's an image in the `<td>` that's of a certain size. I can change the image size on hover, but that has the problem that it loads in the lower resolution and when restored to original size, is grainy and low-res. Essentially, I'm trying to do thumbnails that load small but grow into their full-res size when hovered over.
Here's a rough example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j713vd40

Comment: You'll probably need to construct a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem. Or at least include screen shots.

Comment: Added rough example fiddle. It's showing up vertically rather than horizontally, for some reason.

Comment: does it have to be done in tables? why not divs or something?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I used to use lists but they default to vertical, I want a horizontal collection so I went with tables. Whatever the container, the problem remains the same though; if it starts out transformed to a scale less than 1, it still occupies the same space as if it were at normal scale.

Comment: I would imagine it's because the parent element hasn't been scaled. You're probably better off making the normal state 100%, and scaling _up_ on mouse over instead.

Comment: So, if the 100% scale is the 'normal' state, and I load images into that, the images load at a lower resolution than the original. Therefore, when I scale up anything that scales up the image to its original source size, I get a grainy lower-res version of that image blown up to original size. Since these images involve text, that's not acceptable for my application.